# What are these weird lumps on this spruce tree?

Tags: diseases, spruces

There's a spruce tree growing in a park near my house. It has lumps like this on a lot of the branches.

[image: Spruce picture healthy]

After a while, some of the lumps look like this:

[image: Spruce picture dead-looking]

Is this a disease, or just a part of the tree?

Comment: Spruce gall. Most likely the eastern possibly the adelgid. From my phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment says, these are spruce galls, caused by tiny insects.  For more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall_adelgid